Animating grid-auto-rows property
I have a simple css grid with X grid-items. The number of grid-items can be variable, their sizes can also vary. I need to create a simple expander, so only certain number of rows is going to be visible at first, but after button click event it is going to expand to full height and show all columns.
I have tried to set transition for grid-auto-rows, which would have value of 0fr initially, but the property does not seem to be animatable like gird-template-rows is.


const button = document.querySelector('button');
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
 grid.classList.add('expanded');
});
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 0fr;
  gap: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.grid.expanded {
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}

.grid.expanded + button {
  display: none;
}

.grid-item {
  overflow: hidden;
}
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/100x100">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/100x100">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/100x100">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/100x100">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/100x100">
  </div>
</div>
<button>expand</button>




Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself  preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link.

Does this answer your question? Using CSS transitions in CSS Grid Layout

You can grow the items instead:


const button = document.querySelector('button');
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
 grid.classList.add('expanded');
});
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: max-content;
  gap: 1rem;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  border: solid red 1px;
}

.grid.expanded + button {
  display: none;
}

.grid-item {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grow {
  max-height: 00px;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.expanded .grow {
    max-height: 100px;
}
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/100x100">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/100x100">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/100x100">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/100x100">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grow">
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/100x100">
  </div>
</div>
<button>expand</button>




This however does not work with variable grid-item size. I can't be sure how many items are there in the grid and also what size the item is. Also it requires special markup for items that are initially hidden which kinda makes the reason why I'm trying to make this with grid useless. If I knew what items exactly are going to be hidden beforehand, I would just split the items into two different section and toggle the hidden one. The whole idea of this is that I wanna tell to the grid "show only X rows initially and show the rest after button click" without having to care about the items itself
